# Where can I store Grass?

Tags: farming-simulator-2019

I have a sheep pen that I just fill with store bought grass bales. The issue comes when the sheep "dirty" the pen, as in leave grass scraps in the loading area.

I am able to pick up the grass without issue with my bucket loader, but I cant put the grass back into the feeding area (as the tray is pretty much always full), and I can't store the grass anywhere I've seen, like a storage barn or silo.

Where can I store this excess grass to refill the feeders when the bales run out? Or at the very least 'delete' it, via selling or some other means... so my OCD doesn't go off.

I've tried everything from dumping from the bucket into another trailer to take to the stoarage locations (barn/silo), but nothing seems to accept this "messy" grass.

Do I need to collect it with a baler until eventually all the scrap makes a new bale? I feel like that could work, but it will take a really long time.

I'm playing on Xbox, so editing xml files like in the pc version won't work. the game does support console mods though, so if there is something in the ingame mod marketplace I'm missing that would be acceptable as an answer.

Comment: By dirty, do you mean loose? Because I see [this](https://farmingsimulator.fandom.com/wiki/Grass_(Farming_Simulator_19)#Storing_Loose_Grass) on the wiki. A container or heap may work, but seems like bales are the best way to go

Answer (score 1):

Bucket loaders are annoying IMO. The easiest way is just to buy the biggest "loading wagon" (in the shop Tools -> Loading wagons) that you can afford/your biggest tractor can support, then fill it up and park it next to the animal pen. It will last very long, particularly if you just have sheep. You can even park them next to the animal pen so that it unloads automatically whenever you come near with a tractor - not sure if that's a glitch or a feature. Or park it attached to a tractor.

Grass bales is a convenient format, as you can store it in in piles or on top of some trailer. Hay, straw and silage can be stored in similar fashion and you'll at least want straw no matter animal type. At my horse pen I'm able to drop bales where you are supposed to unload food and then just leave it like that.

Doesn't work for straw though. So at any rate, you'll at a minimum want a front loader of some kind, either a stand-alone vehicle or one you can attach to your regular tractor. Then there's one tool which is a combination of bale spike and bale "crusher" that can turn bales into food. Below Tools -> Animals in the shop there's 3 tools for the front loader - you need to pick one that suits your particular front loader (and pick a front loader that suits the tractor). As usual, save before purchasing equipment you have never used, in case you end up buying the wrong stuff.

You can also buy a trailer PRIMOR 15070 in the same menu, that turns bales to food, but then you need a bale spike tool for the front loader anyway.

If you want to go "industrial" you can buy the large scale mixer wagons that can turn bales into food similarly, but that's mostly useful if you have lots of cows. It's convenient to use one of the telehandlers for large scale bale moving-around.

To get truly "industrial scale", you buy one of the large stand-alone mowers or forage harvesters for gathering massive amounts of grass (normally for the purpose of turning it to silage), then use them with any trailer that can hold grass. In previous farming simulators I bought some 3-4 trailers and hooked them up like a train behind a forage harvester (they have super strong engines). It automatically picks a trailer when one gets full. But this is all expensive equipment, so it's kind of "end game" and I would only bother if you have cows (or really like playing around with these).

And finally a little trick if you bought mowers for your tractor - you can put a mower in front and baler in the back, then go from growing grass to bales straight away. Saves a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

So, after facing the issue a bit more The best solution was to wait until the sheep ate more of the grass. that way I could scoop up the loose grass and just dump it back into the trough.

To let the sheep actually empty the grass out, I just had to move the stack of hay bales out of the feeding area. After that it was a quick time fast forward and the trough emptied enough to clean up.